# Variables imported from the module becomes $null, after the same module imported again

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a simple module: varExp.psm1

> $var1 = 20
>
> Export-ModuleMember -Variable var1

And I import this module into PS session:

> PS> Import-Module .\varExp.psm1

then

> PS> $var1
>
> 20

But after I import it second time

> PS> Import-Module .\varExp.psm1
>
> PS> $var1
>
> PS>

$var1 becomes null...

Anybody knows what is going on here? (PS2.0)

Edit: There are workarounds: Forcing reloading with `Import-Module .\varExp.psm1 -Force`, and testing if module was loaded before: `if(-not (Get-Module varExp)) { Import-Module .\varExp.psm1 }`. But I was hoping to get some reason behind $null value in simple case.

Comment: I think the real WTF here is that Import-Module (without -Force) for a module that has already been imported does not produce an error and does do damage.  Something similar has been reported on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/564927/import-module-fails-to-identify-if-a-module-is-already-loaded-when-the-modulestoprocess-manifest-attribute-contains-a-relative-path)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know exactly what happens, but when you are re-importing a module , you have to use `-Force`.

When you include `-verbose` you can see the difference between the two:

```
PS> import-module .\test -Verbose
VERBOSE: Importing variable 'var1'.
```

With force:

```
PS> import-module .\test -Verbose -Force
VERBOSE: Removing the imported "var1" variable.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\test\test.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Importing variable 'var1'.
```

The documentation does say the following:

> If you import members with the same name and the same type into your
>   session, Windows PowerShell uses the member imported last by default.
>   **Variables and aliases are replaced, and the originals are not
>   accessible.**

I think the `originals are not accessible` means in this `$var1` is not accessible when you re-import the module.

Comment: Thanks! I actually know about -Force and about if(Get-Module ...). The real question here: where is var1 value? If it was replaced - where the replacement's value? Here, documentation or implementation has a bug.

Comment: yeah the issue is that the variable is empty. I have this problem too. I need to import a module several time and only import specific variables

Answer (score 3):

For me @manojlds gives the interesting part of the answer.

Here are some more observations that can help @iank to sleep next night :

when you first load the module you can use the following commande

```
PS> $a = Import-Module .\varExp.psm1 -PassThru
PS> $a.ExportedVariables.var1
Name                           Value
----                           -----
var1                           20
```

Now you change the file .\varExp.psm1 to add a new var $var2=30 and also export it. If you stay in the same powershell you can test. $var2 does not appear.

```
PS> $b = Import-Module .\varExp.psm1 -PassThru
PS> $b.ExportedVariables
Name                           Value
----                           -----
var1
```

For me as you do not remove the module (`Remove-Module varexp`) the module is reloaded from the memory information and vars are really replace but with nothing. If you remove the module or use `-Force` the module is reloaded from file. Try the following :

```
PS> import-module .\varExp.psm1
PS> Remove-Variable var1
PS> import-module .\varExp.psm1
PS> Get-ChildItem variable:
...
var1
...
```

$Var1 is recreated but not assign.