# Powershell run script with Import-Module

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have created a module for my admin group with some functions that automate some procedures we commonly perform (add administrators to remote machines, C drive cleanup, etc...)

One of the prerequisites for these functions is the generation of a series of 7 credentials, one for each domain we work in.

Is there a way to get a scriptblock to run when you import a module, or is this something I should add to each persons profile?

A commenter mentioned I could just add it to the module.psm1 file, but that didn't work.  Here is the code I am trying to run.

```
$creds = Import-Csv [csvfile]
$key = Get-Content [keyfile]
foreach ($cred in $creds) {
    $user = $cred.User
    $password = $cred.Hash | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
    $i = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$password
    New-Variable -Name ($cred.Domain + "_Cred") -Value $i -Force
    }
```

Running this manually works fine, but it isn't creating the credentials when run from the Import-Module command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any code that's not a function will run when you import the module.

Comment: So I can just slap it in the .psm1 file and it'll run?

Comment: Yes. Consider that that is what's happening when you use `Export-ModuleMember` in the module. Try it out with a test module if you need to see behavior or something.

Comment: See above.  It doesn't seem to have worked.  Added the code I am trying to execute.

Comment: @Acerbity do you get any kind of error message? In what way is it not working?

Comment: Well, the code should generate a series of objects.  For instance, $USA_Cred, $DEVSUB_Cred

When I import the module, it doesn't.  No error.

Comment: @Acerbity oh I see what's happening. Those variables are in module scope. They won't be visible outside the module. You could try to export them with `Export-ModuleMember -Variable` ([beware of this though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001496/variables-imported-from-the-module-becomes-null-after-the-same-module-imported)) or you could make them use global scope, like `$Global:creds = whatever`.

Comment: So, can I just create a global variable using that syntax?  Can you think of an easier way to accomplish what I am trying to?  I was considering just putting all of my prequisite code in a script, then having everyone run that script in their profile.

Comment: @Acerbity I think so yes, it may still not extend outside of the module though. In that case, you have to export, or use an exported function to return the variable.

Comment: Copy that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: A handy tip when working with modules: & and . have what may be undocumented functionality. With either you can give two arguments, the first is a module reference (from get-module or similar) and second is a script. With the module reference parameter the script will run in the context of the module. So for example: `& $myMod {$usa_cred}` will output the value of $use_cred even if it hasn't been exported. This is useful for debugging scripts. Also modules can have embedded modules and `& $myMod {gmo}` will list those sub modules. By nesting & or . you can access sub-modules context.

Comment: @user2460798 that's fantastic; deserving of its own answer I think (I'd certainly vote it up).

Comment: @briantist Thanks. I followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

A handy tip when working with modules: `&` and `.` have what may be undocumented functionality. With either you can give two arguments, the first is a module reference (from get-module or similar) and second is a script. With the module reference parameter the script will run in the context of the module. So for example:

```
& $myMod {$usa_cred}
```

will output the value of `$use_cred` even if it hasn't been exported. This is useful for debugging scripts. Also modules can have embedded modules and `& $myMod {gmo}` will list those sub modules. By nesting `&` or `.` you can access sub-modules context.