# How to retrieve exported variable from module?

Tags: powershell, variables, module

How do I retrieve a variable exported from my module after an import?

```
# in mymodule.psm1
$myVar = New-Object VarClass
#assume a function or two here.
Export-Modulemember -Function * -Variable *

# in myScript.ps1 after module import
# how do I reference this variable?
$myScriptVar = $myVar
```

Sorry for the basic question, I cannot find any examples on this simple problem.

Comment: I don't know if `-Variable *` actually works; it could be dangerous what with all the automatic variables. Could you try `-Variable myVar`?

Comment: Tried that already, with `Export-Modulemember -Function myFunc -Variable myVar`

Comment: Hm, this is interesting, maybe this is it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8001496/3905079

Comment: Post the -Variable * as an answer, you've helped me quite a bit today. Also, add that Variables must also be defined by full name in the manifest as well.

Comment: I appreciate that but I'm not clear on what part of my comments worked or helped. If you figured it out mostly on your own you can post a self answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must explicitly state the functions **and** variables in the export module-member cmdlet when exporting both. My problem was that I had a functions as well.

From [powershell documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh849736.aspx):

> If you want to export a variable, in addition to exporting the
>   functions in a module, the Export-ModuleMember command must include
>   the names of all of the functions and the name of the variable.

In this instance I have to have the following in my module:

```
Export-Modulemember -Function Verb-Noun -Variable myVar
```

I got stuck because the same is true in the manifest, you cannot use a wildcard if you're exporting both.

```
# Functions to export from this module
FunctionsToExport = 'Verb-Noun'

# Variables to export from this module
VariablesToExport = 'myVar'
```